# SpringBoot JPA repository save via MariaDB4j

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, repository, mariadb4j

I am having a strange issue when I try to save to a `MariaDBj` from `ApplicationRunner`.

I have created the entities along with a `@service` and a `JpaRepository`. I have added logging so I know that my application is reaching the `RegionEntity savedRegion = repository.save(dummyRegion);` method and I do get an `id` from the `savedRegion` but when I do a `repository.count()` or `repository.findById(...)` I get `0` or an `Optional.EMPTY` respectively.

Moreover using the **same** repository from an API endpoint `/region/created` via a `@Controller` and calling the service backed by the same repo it works and the entity is persisted.

I cannot see why when I use the same repository via `ApplicationRunner`, the entity is not persisted? I am sure that I do not need to flush/commit the transaction. Am also using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`.

```
@Repository
public interface RegionRepository  extends JpaRepository<RegionEntity, Integer>     {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "region_tb")
public class RegionEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4966369808179876078L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String standard;
  private Double price;

}

@Service
public class RegionService {

  private final RegionRepository regionRepository;

  public RegionService(RegionRepository regionRepository) {
    this.regionRepository = regionRepository;
  }

  public void saveRegions() {

    RegionEntity dummyRegion = new  RegionEntity();
    dummyRegion.setName("Test1");
    dummyRegion.setStandard("s1");
    dummyRegion.setPrice(12.99);

    RegionEntity savedRegion =  regionRepository.save(dummyRegion);
    // savedRegion.getId() has valid id 
    Optional<TestVariantEntity> foundRegion = regionRepository.findById(savedRegion.getId());
    // Optional.EMPTY
  }
}

// Application BootStrap
@Component
public class ApplicationBootstrap implements ApplicationRunner {

  private final RegionService regionService;

  @Autowired
  public PriceListDataBootstrap(RegionService regionService) {
    this.regionService = regionService;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    regionService.saveRegions();
  }
}
```

My Depenceies are are such:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.vorburger.mariaDB4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariaDB4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Springboot `2.1.11`. Any help is much appreciated?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with MariaDB4j; as I replace the underling implementation to H2 in memory and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @vorburger
can help probably